# Force import a new version of a file in Vite

Tags: vite, hmr

In my project, I stop full reload by throwing an error in the handler for `vite:beforeFullReload`, and then handle the HMR manually.
When I dynamic import a module, I see that it still imports the old module.
At this point, the generated code is:

```
import('my-module.ts')
```

But after I refresh manually, I see the file has changed to change the import to include `?t=XXXXX`. This causes the updated module to get imported each time after this.
i.e.

```
import('my-module.ts?t=XXXXX')
```

How can I make it so that even for the first time, the import already has `?t=XXXXX` appended to it so that a new version gets downloaded when it is imported?

Answer (score 0):

The HMR is tricky imho, writing hooks for it is more mind boggling that other Vite/Rollup hooks, so I wouldn't recommend it.
The behavior of HMR you described is totally OK, works as expected. To avoid unnecessary caching just turn it off in your Devtools:

[image]